# Mac Computer PHP learning

Tags: php, macos

Hello I'm new in Mac and PHP.

I download MAMP server and Atom editor. I write some code in Atom editor and save as hello.php but when i tried to open page, it could open atom editor page.

here is my code. What should i do?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> PHP Hello </title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<b>
  <h1>
<?php
  print "Hello World";

?>
</h1>
</b>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: run it throught your browser and enter `localhost/hello.php` in the address bar

Comment: save your file in `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/hello.php`

then open browser and enter url  http://localhost/project/hello.php

Comment: in htdocs, i dont have project file

Comment: @user3748265 project is not a file but a folder. Create the folder and put hello.php there.

Answer (score 1):

How do you open the page ? If the page is in your `www` (or whatever it is named on MAMP), you have to type in your browser

> http://localhost/hello.php

or (strictly equivalent)

> http://127.0.0.1/hello.php